# Google maps api trying to get address using place id in hindi

Tags: php, google-maps, curl

I'm trying to get address using `place_id` in hindi but I'm getting some special characters. Please someone help me.

```
<?php 

    $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJLbZ-NFv9DDkRzk0gTkm3wlI&language=hi&key=AIzaSyBt7SRPMKW4pWc06NwuzFNCErXxnIlyEIY';



    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // OPEN CONNECTION 
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        echo curl_error($ch);
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    $result=json_decode($result);
    //pr($result);  

    echo "<pre>";print_r($result->result->formatted_address);

?>
```

Comment: probably a charset issue. you need to make sure you tell your output environment what charset your google results are in. e.g. if google sends back utf-8 text, and you're dumping it into an iso8859 environment, you are going to get "special characters".

Comment: so what i have to do.